# iOS - Resizing an image is causing a memory leak

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimage

I am trying to resize several `UIImage` objects inside a `for` loop using the following code:

```
CGFloat scaledToWidth:resized_width = 160.0;
for(UIImage *img in imageArray) {
    UIImage *resizedImageSecond = [self resizeImage:img scaledToWidth:resized_width]; 
    //Do something with resizedImageSecond      
}

-(UIImage*)resizeImage:(UIImage*) sourceImage scaledToWidth: (float) i_width
{
    float oldWidth = sourceImage.size.width;
    float scaleFactor = i_width / oldWidth;

    float newHeight = sourceImage.size.height * scaleFactor;
    float newWidth = oldWidth * scaleFactor;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(newWidth, newHeight));
    [sourceImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

But I see my memory usage rapidly increase over every iteration of `resizeImage:scaledToWidth:`. I don't see any obious memory leaks here, but I'm not sure either.

Does anyone see any reason why my memory usage would increase in this function? I'm at a loss here. Unfortunately, I have about 100 `UIImage` inside `imageArray`, so I need to be as conservative with memory as possible.

Comment: If you're releasing the resized image after its creation, then wrap the body of the loop in an `@autoreleasepool` block.  If not, then you'll need to find a less resource intensive method than a straight loop.

Comment: @CodaFi My project is ARC, so I'm not explicitly releasing it anywhere. Should I be?

Comment: Also, use Instruments and learn to deploy Allocations Leaks tools and see the leaks with the list of which callers are incrementing and decrementing refcounts. It's an invaluable learning tool as well as a debugging tool.

Comment: ARC or not, the `@autoreleasepool` directive is available to use.  Take a look here if you're confused as to their usage: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html

Comment: @RobP I've tried Instruments. I was under the impression that its not trivial to pick up `CoreFoundation` objects tho, which is what is backing the `UIImage`. If I'm wrong, I'll look into it deeper.

Comment: Show the code, that goes under 'Do something with resizedImageSecond'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create new `UIImage` instance on every usage of `resizeImage:scaledToWidth:`. That's the reason of memory increasing. The simplest solution is to set the image to `nil` when it's not needed anymore.

```
for(UIImage *img in imageArray) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        UIImage *resizedImage = [self resizeImage:img scaledToWidth:resized_width]; 

        //Do something with resizedImage 

        resizedImage = nil;
    }     
}
```

Comment: So why, in an ARC project (like mine), does it not get released when it goes out of scope? (i.e., continuing the loop?)

Comment: I actually have set `resizedImage = nil`, and there's no change.

Comment: ARC makes no guarantees about object lifecycles.  All you know is that  the locals will get released at some point.  This could potentially do absolutely nothing to fix the problem.

Comment: @IgorMatyushkin Still no luck. The memory still increases with every iteration of the loop. And the memory is still retained after the loop  and the method exit. My code is exactly as I have above. If I don't call `resizeImage`, it works fine. This leads me to believe there is something wrong in `resizeImage`. Hence my comments in my OP. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible you're doing something to retain this new batch of images?  Maybe putting them in a data structure, or perhaps holding a strong reference to them with a different object?

Comment: Currently, for debugging, I am not even using `resizedImage`. At the end of the loop, I set it to `nil`. I do see that the memory jumps on the line: `[sourceImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight)];` in the `resizeImage:` method.

Comment: Yeah, then this isn't a memory leak.  You need to ditch the for-in loop for batch processing and chunk up the work you're trying to do into something more manageable.  Maybe try not doing heavy image processing with a for loop on a resource-constrained device.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I ended out getting rid of the loop. I tested your code above in another setting, and works great. So answer accepted :-)